# PayPal Integration auto deduct

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, paypal

Hi everyone I have integrated PayPal in my iOS app my concern is can we automatically deduct the amount from PayPal or cc after a particular event happens in the app if so how we can achieve that.

Comment: your question seems bit unclear. Add more details.

Comment: @Mayur I have a task in my app after which amount should be deducted from their PayPal or cc can we do that. say for example if driver drops passenger at destination amount should be auto deducted from passenger app.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's definitely possible as it's just a matter of making API calls. The SDK should handle it for you, but if not you could always build the requests yourself.
2. You could do either a parallel payment (where the payer would see both receivers during checkout) or a chained payment (where the payer would only see the primary receiver during checkout.)

You'll make a request to the [Pay API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) with a primary receiver set to the seller and the secondary receiver set to you.

You'll set the primary receiver amount the full amount and the secondary receiver to their amount accordingly. For example, if $10 is paid the primary receiver amount would be $10 (not $8) and the secondary receiver would be $2.

I would definitely recommend reviewing the [Adaptive Payments documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/) which has a lot of detail about chained payments and how it all works.

3. Both transactions will automatically happen when the payer completes the checkout.